# How to setup custom elements with svelte + rails/webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, web-component, svelte, webpacker

I've been trying to setup svelte custom elements with webpacker. This is loaders/svelte.js

```js
module.exports = {
  test: /\.svelte$/,
  use: [{
    loader: 'svelte-loader',
    options: {
      hotReload: true,
      customElement: true
    }
  }],
}
```

here is my svelte pack

```js
require.context('../components', true, /\.svelte$/);
```

For some reason, the webcomponents aren't rendering. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use [svelte-rails gem](https://github.com/nning/svelte-rails) or examine how it works and sprinkle its approach to your code

Comment: I used
$ rails webpacker:install:svelte
already i think the problem has to do with my webpack require line, although I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Please add any error messages observed to your post please, from the rails and web browser consoles. Thanks

Comment: there weren't any errors

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hazg/0efd24bd23ec879c23cac28dd29f33f5

But it's not webpacker